# Como editar dados de uma Table após postback em ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabela-html

Tenho uma Table em um Web Form em ASP.NET e logo abaixo no mesmo form adicionei umas TextBox em que você preenche os campos para adicionar uma nova linha à Table. A parte de insersão na tabela funciona muito bem, mas apenas uma vez na segunda vez que tento adicionar outra linha à tabela a anterior desaparece e essa nova linha fica no seu lugar e assim sucessivamente.

**ASP.NET**

```aspnet
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Table ID="TableAutores" runat="server" Caption="<b>Autores</b>" BorderWidth="2px" BorderStyle="Solid">
                <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server" Font-Bold="true">
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell>Nome</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell>Sobrenome</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>AAA</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>AAA</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>BBB</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>BBB</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>CCC</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>CCC</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
            <br />
            <asp:Label Text="Nome" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNome" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label Text="Sobrenome" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSobrenome" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdicionar" Text="Adicionar autor" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonAdicionar_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**C#**

```c#
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void ButtonAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell nome = new TableCell();
        TableCell sobrenome = new TableCell();
        nome.Text = TextBoxNome.Text;
        sobrenome.Text = TextBoxSobrenome.Text;
        TableRow linha = new TableRow();
        linha.Cells.Add(nome);
        linha.Cells.Add(sobrenome);
        TableAutores.Rows.Add(linha);
    }
}
```

Aparentemente estou inserindo os dados na Table original e não na Table da página de postback. O engraçado é que fiz o mesmo com uma ListBox e funcionou, consegui adicionar mais de um item.

O que devo fazer para conseguir adicionar uma linha na Table da página de postback (se esse é o termo correto a se utilizar)? Existe algum atributo que preciso modificar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zignd, veja aqui: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table(v=vs.110).aspx

> It is important to remember that any programmatic addition or modification of table rows or cells will not persist across posts to the server. This is because table rows and cells are controls of their own, and not properties of the Table control. To persist any changes to the table, rows and cells must be reconstructed after each postback.

Traduzindo, as linhas e células adicionadas na Table tem que ser reconstruídas em cada postback.

Ou seja, você tem que armazenar o conteúdo das linhas que você insere na Table em algum outro lugar, e adicionar todas elas em algum momento, provavelmente no Page_Load. Para isso você tem algumas opções:

- Viewstate - Vantagem de ficar na própria página, mas cuidado pois pode tornar o carregamento muito lento
- Session - Mantém no servidor os dados, geralmente em memória, ou seja o acesso é rápido. Porém se for muitos dados também pode te causar problemas.
- Banco de dados, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa reconstruir sua tabela com esse novo valor o que pode implicar em criá-la totalmente no code behind. Uma outra opção que talvez facilite seu trabalho é utilizar uma gridview, armazenar o datasource na viewstate e dar o bind() após o postback.